# disableStaticImages not working in my next project

Tags: next.js, next-images

I have two projects, both of them with the same code in my `next.config.js` file:

```js
const withImages = require("next-images");

/* ... */

module.exports = withImages({
  images: {
    disableStaticImages: true,
  },

  /* ... */

});
```

However, when you see at the DOM, you'll notice that one project is showing inline images as base64 string in it's img `src` attribute, whereas the other one is showing a reference link to a static file instead.

The project showing inline images is the version `12.0.8` of next.js, and the project showing a static file link reference is the version `12.0.9`.

Any idea how to make the second project show inline images in base64?

Comment: Are both identical projects (in addition to the config being the same?) did you find a solution?